# Having .net core project with 2 different model properties

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Having .net core project with 2 different model with 2 forms  now requirement is after filling form1 if user wants to fill form2 then some common properties should be populated automatically how can we get done this in asp.net core if any one can guide ?

in short we need to display some data from form1 to form2

Comment: If you want to show / populate some HTML based on some other HTML, it's not ASP related issue, it's purely front-end. Server side should always render all fields, some of them will be hidden. Then in UI, you need to listen to `change` in the input and when user enters something, show some hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting form1 to form2 action,and then pass the data of form1 to view form2.Here is a demo:
Models:

```
public class Model1
    {
        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }

    }
    public class Model2
    {
        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult Form1()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Form2(Model1 m1)
        {
            Model2 m2 = new Model2 { Id1 = m1.Id1, Name1 = m1.Name1 };
            return View();
        }
```

View(Form1):

```
@model Model1
    <form id="form1" method="post" asp-action="Form2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Id1</label>
            <input asp-for="Id1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name1</label>
            <input asp-for="Name1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

View(Form2):

```
@model Model2 
<form id="form2" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Id1</label>
        <input asp-for="Id1" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name1</label>
        <input asp-for="Name1" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Id2</label>
        <input asp-for="Id2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name2</label>
        <input asp-for="Name2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but my forms are not on same page unfortunate

Comment: I have updated my answer to pass form1 data to form2 which are in seperated views.

Comment: @RajBhatia If you have a wizzard form with multiple steps and pages. You will need to pass the data between HTTP requests, when form is submitted, you receive this data in the controller action and redirect to the next page. You can pass parameters to the next page in MVC way https://www.infoworld.com/article/3568209/how-to-pass-parameters-to-action-methods-in-asp-net-core-mvc.html or using HTTP context - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0